# How to update a column value by another column(foreign key) in another table

Tags: mysql

I had made a student table link with report table by foreign key to join them.

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    st_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(st_id),
    student_name varchar(100),
    student_id varchar(9),
    email varchar(100),
    pass varchar(100),
    tp_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (tp_id) REFERENCES Training_programs(tp_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Report (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    st_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (st_id) REFERENCES Students(st_id),
    status VARCHAR(100)
);
```

But my problem is when i insert status that i can't insert st_id in the same time because i just insert status in my web. So that i try to auto insert st_id from Students to Report after insert status report:

```
CREATE TRIGGER thistrigger BEFORE INSERT
ON Students FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Report, Students SET Report.st_id = Students.st_id WHERE Report.st_id IS NULL;
```

But it can't work. So that do every ones have any solution with my problem?

Comment: If a report is related to a student (a specific student) then you must know which Student (`Student.st_id`) this report relates to before you can insert a Report row. You must be adding Reports to a specific student, you cannot be inserting random reports, thats not logical

Comment: I agree with @RiggsFolly, our application must supply the student id when a report is created. If it does not, then you have to change your application logic.

Comment: If you gave us some idea of the workflow that gets you to creating a Report, we could probably spot where you are not collecting or passing the `st_id` to the Report creation process